# iOS Rich notifications not working correctly

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, swift4, rich-notifications

I need to implement rich notification in current application with image.

I have implemented everything and its working fine. And receiving push notification, but getting only title and message but not image as attachments

Normal notifications without mutable-content work fine.

As far as I tested, there is no problem with certificate side.. I am using NotificationService extension to show media attachment

Any idea?

My payload looks like below:

```
[AnyHashable("title"): New trailer released- Hindi Movies, AnyHashable("message"): Kuchh Bheege Alfaaz - Official Hindi Trailer, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "New trailer released- Hindi Movies";
    badge = 2;
    sound = default;
}, AnyHashable("trailer_img"): uploads/trailer_image/9703831856a7968b8b5cf6b10357dc2c1.jpg]
```

My NotificationService Class code like below:

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler : ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var content        : UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest,
                             withContentHandler contentHandler:
        @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        self.content        = (request.content.mutableCopy()
            as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        let userInfo : [AnyHashable: Any] = request.content.userInfo
        print(userInfo)

        if let bca = self.content {

            func save(_ identifier: String,
                      data: Data, options: [AnyHashable: Any]?)
                -> UNNotificationAttachment? {

                    let directory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString,
                                                                                                        isDirectory: true)

                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: directory,
                                                                withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                                attributes: nil)
                        let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(identifier)
                        try data.write(to: fileURL, options: [])
                        return try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: identifier,
                                                                 url: fileURL,
                                                                 options: options)

                    } catch {
                    }

                    return nil
            }

            func exitGracefully(_ reason: String = "") {
                let bca    = request.content.mutableCopy()
                    as? UNMutableNotificationContent
                bca!.title = reason

                contentHandler(bca!)
            }

           let reachability = Reachability()!

            reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {

                        guard let content = (request.content.mutableCopy()
                            as? UNMutableNotificationContent) else {
                                return exitGracefully()
                        }

                        let userInfo : [AnyHashable: Any] = request.content.userInfo
                        print(userInfo)
                        guard let attachmentURL = userInfo["trailer_img"]
                            as? String else {
                                return exitGracefully()
                        }

                        guard let imageData  =
                            try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "http://techindiana.com/dev/truetrailer_app/" + attachmentURL)!)
                            else {
                                return exitGracefully()
                        }

                        guard let attachment =
                            save("image.png", data: imageData, options: nil)
                            else {
                                return exitGracefully()
                        }

                        content.attachments = [attachment]
                        contentHandler(content.copy() as! UNNotificationContent)

                    } else {

                        return exitGracefully()
                    }
                }
            }

            reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    return exitGracefully()
                }
            }

            do {
                try reachability.startNotifier()
            } catch {
                return exitGracefully()
            }
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {

        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bca =  self.content {
            contentHandler(bca)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add your code in question

Comment: where is `mutable-content` key in Payload?

Comment: mutable-content not getting from backend side (PHP)

Comment: `mutable-content` is mandatory for Rich Notification.

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/@prianka.kariat/ios-10-notifications-with-attachments-and-much-more-169a7405ddaf

Comment: This also: https://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/

Comment: Now working fine....